# What would be a good heuristic to solving this?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

The aim is to guide a bot from Source `S` to Goal `G` while passing through all the checkpoints `@` (in any order).

```
########
#@....G#
##.##@##
#..@..S#
#@.....#
########
```

One way to solve it would be to select one checkpoint as goal from current state and then guide the bot to it. Then select the next checkpoint as goal and current checkpoint as source and guide the bot to its new goal. Eventually guide it to the state `G` from the last checkpoint.
But this technique relies heavily on the order of checkpoints traversed.
 I would like to know if a good heuristic can be found to decide which checkpoint to go to next?

Comment: If you're not particularly asking for a robot to do it, stackoverflow would give you much better answers.

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem is called the travelling salesman problem, which is a heavily studied problem. The [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) lists a few heuristics in the middle.